# Wildfly standalone.xml - passing secret to KeyCloak SPI from elytron credential store

Tags: configuration, wildfly, keycloak

I'm migrating KeyCloak v15 (WildFly v23) passwords from the old vault to elytron credential store. It works fine for the standard use case. In `standalone.xml`, I have:
`/server/extensions/extension`:

```xml
<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.elytron"/>
```

`/server/profile/subsystem`:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:elytron:13.0" final-providers="elytron" disallowed-providers="OracleUcrypto">
    <providers>
        <provider-loader name="elytron" module="org.wildfly.security.elytron"/>
    </providers>
    <audit-logging>
        <file-audit-log name="local-audit" path="audit-log.log" relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" format="JSON"/>
    </audit-logging>
    <credential-stores>
        <credential-store name="credStore" location="/data/credStore.jceks">
            <implementation-properties>
                <property name="keyStoreType" value="JCEKS"/>
            </implementation-properties>
            <credential-reference clear-text="MASK-123456789;salt123;42"/>
        </credential-store>
    </credential-stores>
</subsystem>
```

and I access the passwords using
`/server/profile/subsystem[@xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:8.0"]/stacks/stack[@name="tcp"]/auth-protocol/digest-token/shared-secret-reference`:

```xml
<shared-secret-reference store="credStore" alias="myBlock::mySecret"/>
```

---

However, there is one secret I need to pass to a SPI in a property. Any idea how to do it? This was the old vault way:

`/server/system-properties/property`:

```xml
<property name="secret" value="${VAULT::myBlock::mySecret::1}"/>
```

`/server/profile/subsystem[@xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak-server:1.1"]/spi`:

```xml
<spi name="mySpi">
    <provider name="file" enabled="true">
        <properties>
            <property name="password" value="${secret}"/>
        </properties>
    </provider>
</spi>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to rewrite our SPI to read Elytron credential store contents:

```java
import org.jboss.as.server.CurrentServiceContainer;
import org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceController;
import org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceName;
import org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.wildfly.security.credential.PasswordCredential;
import org.wildfly.security.credential.store.CredentialStore;
import org.wildfly.security.credential.store.CredentialStoreException;
import org.wildfly.security.password.Password;
import org.wildfly.security.password.interfaces.ClearPassword;
```

```java
  private static String getClientSecret(String credentialStore, String secretAlias) {
    final ServiceName SERVICE_NAME_CRED_STORE = ServiceName.of("org", "wildfly", "security", "credential-store");
    final ServiceName sn = ServiceName.of(SERVICE_NAME_CRED_STORE, credentialStore);
    final ServiceRegistry registry = CurrentServiceContainer.getServiceContainer();
    final ServiceController<?> credStoreService = registry.getService(sn);
    final CredentialStore cs = (CredentialStore) credStoreService.getValue();
//    if (!cs.exists(secretAlias, PasswordCredential.class)) {
//      throw new CredentialStoreException("Alias " + secretAlias + " not found in credential store.");
//    }
    final Password password;
    try {
      password = cs.retrieve(secretAlias, PasswordCredential.class).getPassword();
    } catch (CredentialStoreException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }
    if (!(password instanceof ClearPassword)) {
      throw new ClassCastException("Password is not of type ClearPassword");
    }
    return new String(((ClearPassword) password).getPassword());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 possibilities:

1. Rewrite the SPI to retrieve the secret directly from Elytron credential store in Java
2. Set an environment variable beforehand (`export SECRET="$(secret-getter-script)"`) and use the variable in `standalone.xml`:

```xml
<spi name="mySpi">
    <provider name="file" enabled="true">
        <properties>
            <property name="password" value="${env.SECRET}"/>
        </properties>
    </provider>
</spi>
```

Comment: In the end, using an environment variable wasn't safe enough for our use and I had to teach our SPI to read Elytron credential store contents